# Can anyone give explanation for below two statements on centre of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

- **Statement 1:** Centre of mass cannot be accelerated by internal forces
- **Statement 2:** Action point of external force is immaterial in producing acceleration in centre of mass

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is a result of Newton's 3rd law. Each internally generated force has an equal but opposite component also acting within the body resulting in *zero* change in the *net* force of the body.

The second statement is a result of Newton's 2nd law. The explanation goes like this.

- The total momentum of a body is the sum of each particle momentum and it is a property of the whole body and not of any point on the body.
- Newton's 2nd law equates the *net* force acting on a body to the change in momentum. There is no mention of the location of any applied force when calculating *net* force.

  When you study the law of rotational motion, then the location of any applied force becomes important.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation